# Configuration Specific Variable Values in Windows Phone 8 Apps

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

What I want to do is set different variable values depending on the current configuration. So when I run the project in Debug, I would like the app to point towards my development stack. When I run the app in Release I would like the app to run against my production stack. And I would like to create a Beta config which will be mostly the same as my Release config settings but slightly different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Slow Cheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/) extension for Visual Studio. It allows you to transform you config files based on the current build configuration.

Alternatively you could use [Conditional Compilation Symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). But I'd recommend the config transforms.

**EDIT:**

Seeing as you are unable to use the configuration transforms I think you're forced to go do the route of compilation symbols. So I'd create the configuration files and then have a class use compilation symbols to read the correct one at runtime. Something along the lines of:

```
public class ConfigurationLoader()
{
    private readonly string _configFile;

    public ConfigurationLoader()
    {
        #if DEBUG 
            _configFile = "app.Debug.config"; 
        #else 
            _configFile = "app.Release.config";
        #endif
    }

    public UniversalAppConfig LoadCofig()
    {
        // Read file

        // Create UniversalAppConfig
    }
}

public class UniversalAppConfig()
{
    public int ConfigurationValueA { get; set; }

    public int ConfigurationValueB { get; set; }
}
```

You set the symbols under Project Properties -> Build by the way.

Comment: Slow Cheetah sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm trying to do this in a Universal App that supports Windows Phone Store and Windows Store apps, but the Slow Cheetah package does not seem to be compatible with this type of project.

Comment: in the project settings for your project, there is a place you can define additional symbols.  you would go into one of the projects, and add a define for MY_SPECIAL_THING, and don't set it in the other project.  then, in your code, you'd use `#if MY_SPECIAL_THING` around the places where it should compile.

Comment: I'm already using compilation symbols for some things, but I was hoping there was a built in way to handle this. I think your solution is the best one since it gives me exactly what I want with only a little bit of work. Thank you.

Comment: After thinking about this for a little while, I have another question. I always have security in mind and suppose I want to store things like secret keys in these config files. Should I be worried about someone unpacking the appxbundle file and finding my secret keys?